# How to build mailcore2 library for android

Tags: android, android-ndk, mailcore2

I have never used Android-NDK before and here comes the problem when I want to compile [mailcore2](https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/blob/master/build-android/README.md#build-for-android) library for android on windows. There is not much explanation given on compiling the library. Can someone please help me with this?

Also, I can run the application on emulator using given *.aar but when I run it on device I get the following error:

```
03-23 12:53:54.223 27409-27409/com.libmailcore.androidexample A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x766e6f6f in tid 27409 (.androidexample)
03-23 12:53:55.063 27449-27449/com.libmailcore.androidexample A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x766e6f6f in tid 27449 (.androidexample)
```

What is the fix for this?

Thanks

Comment: The builds instructions are here: https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/tree/master/build-android

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà thanks for your response. Can you please tell me why this is not working on device? Do I need to compile my own *.aar and use it in project to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: The build system has been designed to work on Unix platform (and probably Mac).

Comment: Do you mean that I compile library in UNIX or Mac as well as build android project in UNIX or Mac?